# Use gsub when I match specific column

Tags: bash, awk, string-substitution

I have an original file containing a table of DNA base sequences, with row and column labels, and a separate "position" file listing a subset of the column labels.  I need to process the original file, performing a transformation on the values from the columns identified by the position file.

Example original file:

```
name pos1 pos2 pos3 pos4 pos5 pos6 pos7
name1 AT TA CT GT CC TC TT
name2 AA TA TT GT TC TC TT
name3 AT TT CG AT CT TC TT
name4 GT TA CT TT CC TC TT
```

Example position file:

```
pos1
pos3
pos6
pos7
```

On each of the selected fields I need to perform these translations:

```
A to T
C to G
G to C
T to A
```

Thus, the output obtained by processing the example original file based on the provided position file would be:

```
name pos1 pos2 pos3 pos4 pos5 pos6 pos7
name1 TA TA GA GT CC AG AA
name2 TT TA AA GT TC AG AA
name3 TA TT GC AT CT AG AA
name4 CA TA GA TT CC AG AA
```

So the first line is unmodified, and on each subsequent line the fields corresponding to column labels `pos1`, `pos3`, `pos6`, and `pos7` are transformed, whereas the other fields are preserved unchanged.

I know how to use `awk` to apply `gsub()` to modify whole input lines or to modify the n<sup>th</sup> field specifically, but I need to modify only those fields listed in the position file, as identified by the column labels on the first line of the data file.  How can I implement that in `awk`?

Comment: @EdMorton He wants to do the substitutions only in the selected columns.

Comment: Do you need to preserve the amount and type of whitespace between columns?  Would it be ok to, say, convert each in-line whitespace runs into a single space character?

Comment: @EdMorton, no, I'm pretty confident that he wants to perform all four substitutions on each selected field.  Confident enough that I edited the question to say so, in fact.

Comment: @EdMorton yes I need to substitutions only selected columns (according to my position file). CT became GA, because there is translations... gsub ("C","G");gsub("T","A")... Of course skip header. I hoe it is much more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split("A T C G G C T A",t)
    for (i=1;i in t;i+=2) {
        map[t[i]] = t[i+1]
    }
}
NR==FNR {
    fldNames[$1]
    next
}
FNR==1 {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i in fldNames) {
            targets[i]
        }
    }
}
FNR>1 {
    $0 = tolower($0)
    for (fldNr in targets) {
        for (old in map) {
            gsub(tolower(old),map[old],$fldNr)
        }
    }
    $0 = toupper($0)
}
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk positions original
name pos1 pos2 pos3 pos4 pos5 pos6 pos7
NAME1 TA TA GA GT CC AG AA
NAME2 TT TA AA GT TC AG AA
NAME3 TA TT GC AT CT AG AA
NAME4 CA TA GA TT CC AG AA
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that it is not essential to preserve the exact field (column) separators -- that is, that you are free to change every column separator into a fixed string, such as a single space -- you can use `gsub()` on a per-field basis and then reconstruct the record afterward.  This takes care of the problem of limiting the changes to specific fields.

The other problem is to identify *which* fields to modify, based on data from the positions file and on the column headings.  Here's one way to do that:

- using a `BEGIN` block, read each line from the positions file and record its contents as an array index.  You can think of this as recording the contents of each line in a hash table.
- Match the pre-read column labels to the column labels read from the first line of the main input by looping over the fields and checking for their presence in the array of labels.  For those that are present, record the field *number* as an index in a second array
- for each subsequent line rebuild the record from its constituent fields, choosing between the original value and the modified value based on whether the field number is recorded as one of those that needs to be transformed.
- note in particular that `awk` can reference fields by field numbers stored in variables.  Thus, `myfield = 2; print $myfield` produces the same output as `print $2`

An `awk` program that does all that might look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

function baseswap(seq) {
  gsub(/A/, "X", seq)
  gsub(/T/, "A", seq)
  gsub(/X/, "T", seq)
  gsub(/C/, "X", seq)
  gsub(/G/, "C", seq)
  gsub(/X/, "G", seq)
  return seq
}

BEGIN  {
         while ((getline < "positions") == 1) {
           labels[$1] = 1
         }
       }

FNR==1 {
          for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
            if (labels[$i]) {
              fields[i] = 1
            }
          }
          print
          next
       }

       {
         record = $1
         for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
           record = record " " (fields[i] == 1 ? baseswap($i) : $i)
         }
         print record
       }
```

Comment: Thank you John for your edit and answer. I do not need preserve field separator - I can fix it in new awk script. Maybe stupid question, but how can I run this script? Where to put position file? Thank you so much..

Comment: @Paul, I put the position file and the script both in the working directory, and ran it via the command `awk -f baseswap.awk < original`.  Since there is a shebang line, you should also be able to run it as simply `baseswap.awk < original`, provided that you set the file's mode to make it executable.  You could also extend the script to take the name of the position file from a command-line argument, or to input the position labels in some other way.

Comment: FWIW whenever I want a temp string that can't be present in the input I just use `RS`, e.g. `gsub(/A/,RS)` instead of `gsub(/A/,"X")`. Also I'm not convinced getline is required to return exactly 1 on success, nor an I convinced the operator precedence is what you're assuming. To be safe, I'd write it as `while ( (getline < "positions") > 0 ) {`

Comment: @EdMorton, fair point about `RS`, though in this problem domain I don't think that's an issue.  As for `getline`'s return value, the `gawk` docs say "The 'getline' command returns one if it finds a record and zero if it encounters the end of the file.  If there is some error [it] returns
-1."  The POSIX specs for `awk` say the same thing, in different words.  And as for operator precedence, the fact that the script works supports the expectations about precedence implicit within.

Comment: John - I agree you're probably fine with "X" instead of RS it was just a general thing. I think you're right about 1. The fact your script works just proves it works on the version of awk you're currently running, it doesn't mean it'll work in other awks. From POSIX `The getline operator can form ambiguous constructs when there are unparenthesized binary operators (including concatenate) to the right of the '<' (up to the end of the expression containing the getline).`. Does that mean `getline < file == 1` **needs** parens? Honestly idk but it certainly doesn't hurt.

Comment: @EdMorton, I have added parentheses around the `getline` command, as you suggest.  The way I read POSIX, they are required for conformance: "[...] conforming applications shall parenthesize properly all such usages."  Anyway, they don't hurt anything.